# Two way table and django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

Consider two django models 'User' and 'BoardGame', the latter has a ManyToMany field 'vote' defined with a custom through table:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    boardgame = models.ForeignKey(BoardGame)
    vote = models.IntegerField()
```

I need to print a two way table having users names on the top, boardgames names on the left column and votes in the middle.

Is there a way to obtain this using django? (Remember that a user might not have voted every single boardgame.)

**UPDATE: MORE DETAILS**

1) Clearly this can be work out using some lines of python (which probably would result in many queries to the database), but I'm more interested in discovering if there is something directly implemented in django that could do the work. After all a ManyToMany field is nothing but a two way table (in this case with some data associated).

2) A possible 'solution' would be a FULL OUTER JOIN using a raw query, but, again, I am looking for something built-in inside django.

3) More specifically I'm using Class Based View and I was wondering if there exists an appropriate query to associate to queryset parameter of ListView.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The model defines the database schema so yes in theory you will be able to store and retrieve the data you want but you need to build your views and templates (plus any css or js) to display the table

Comment: Please see the update section in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...

class BoardGame(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Vote')
    ...

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    boardgame = models.ForeignKey(BoardGame)
    vote = models.IntegerField()
```

would work like this:

```
from django.db import connections, reset_queries
reset_queries()

users = User.objects.all().prefetch_related('vote_set')
table = []
table.append([''] + list(users))
for board_game in BoardGame.objects.all().prefetch_related('vote_set'):
    row = [board_game]
    for user in users:
        for vote in user.vote_set.all():
            if vote in board_game.vote_set.all():
                row.append(vote)
                break
        else:
            row.append('')
    table.append(row)

len(connection.queries)  # Returns always 4
```

This is not the solution you wanted, but it shows a way to get the table from the database with only 4 queries no matter how many objects you have.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to obtain this with a single query? Basically I need django to do a FULL OUTER JOIN. See also the update section in my question.

Comment: The table I proposed here is a nested list. If you want to get only  one queryset this would never be nested. The queryset should contain which objects? Users, BoardGames, Votes or all of them? May be a short example would be helpful?

Comment: The queryset would contain just Vote objects but also those tuples that actually haven't a vote, thus are not memorized in the database, i.e. a user might have voted some boardgames but not all of them. The result should be something like [this](http://syllabus.bos.nsw.edu.au/assets/mathematicsk10/images/s3sp004.png) but some numbers (i.e., votes) may be missing.

Comment: If I'd use `Vote.objects.all()` I would miss all (user,boardgame) pair that haven't a vote associated and it would be a mess to render such queryset inside template.

Comment: I refactored the solution so you are able to get your table with 4 db queries.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll use this one (even if I'm a bit disappointed by django's skill). For sake of completeness: I tried using `Vote.objects.raw("CUSTOM_QUERY")` but it complains when dealing with `NULL` values since he tries to return real Vote instances. The most efficient way to do this using only one query is still writing manually a custom query (completely avoiding django ORM).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything in the Django core or generic Class Based Views that will render tables for you, but try [django-tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: I am not strictly interested in something that render the table, I'd settle for a way to retrieve a queryset which satisfy my needs.